# Greasemonkey - How do you click this hidden button of this youglish.com page?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am new to Greasemonkey and javascript. I have a youglish.com page: URL: https://youglish.com/pronounce/get%20caught%20off%20guard/english/us?

I'd like to have GreaseMonkey in Chrome (Tampermonkey) automatically click this button "[share]" after page loading and then click "Copy link" that appears (so that I can copy the URL to the clipboard) (see the two pictures[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdHxX.png) below)

Here is my code, but after I load it nothing happens .. what did I do wrong? I suspect it's the button id in the getElementById(...) I specified not correct, but not sure

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youglish button click
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://youglish.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load',  function(){
        document.getElementById("Share").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
        document.getElementById("Copy link").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    });
})();
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Greasemonkey but you are trying to fetch a document's element by id but the element doesn't have any, the text in it is NOT the element's id, you can learn more about it here: [MDN Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).

The link given in share thing is just the page's url, you can simply copy it by using:

> document.location.href

if it is what you are trying to achieve.

if it is not then please let me know in more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Shyne. This is very useful. I can't find anything in the page source that looks like the id of that two buttons (e.g., this is the [Share] button: [<a href="#" data-trgid="a_share" class="menu_ttl openShare" role="button">Share</a>]). BTW, the page URL and link of the button are not the same. the copied link has video id in it https://youglish.com/getbyid/124594354/get%20caught%20off%20guard/english/us

Comment: @JustinLin I checked again and the links are different, however the page's URL works fine to share the page too, especially since the share link is not a shortened URL (like youtube for example: the share links use the youtu.be domain instead of youtube.com and have a short id after it)

Answer (score 0):

A few things you should keep in mind.  First the DOMContentLoaded event fires then the page fetches additional content from the server.  Since the link we are looking for is one of those fetched items we have to wait for it which is why setInterval was used.  Once we find the link we use the copyLinkLoaded function to clearInterval.  Javascript makes it difficult to copy something to the clipboard automatically so direct clicking of the button will not work.  Once the link is available we can use its href property and copy that if we use @grant GM_setClipboard.  Let me know if this script works for you.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youglish button click
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @match        https://youglish.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// ==/UserScript==

var copyLinkClear;

let copyLinkLoaded = () => {
  clearInterval(copyLinkClear);
  console.log('the interval has been cleared');
}

let findCopyLink = () => {
  copyLinkClear = setInterval(() => {
    const link = document.querySelectorAll('[class="tb_copy"] > [class="nodec"]')[0];
    if (link) {
      console.log(`The link to be copied is: ${link.href}`);
      GM_setClipboard(link.href);
      copyLinkLoaded();
    } else {
      console.log('The link has not loaded yet');
    }
  }, 100)
}

let findshareLinkLink = () => {
  const shareLink = document.querySelector('[data-trgid="a_share"]');
  if (shareLink) {       // We make sure the shareLink button was selected properly
    shareLink.click();  // We click on the shareLink button.
    console.log('The shareLink button was clicked');
    findCopyLink();
  } else {
    console.log('The shareLink button was not properly selected');
  }
}

findshareLinkLink();
```

Comment: This almost works. Just I don't need @grant GM_setClipboard. simply clicking the "Copy link" button works fine

Comment: I will accept this anwser. but I run into an issue with the code above: the first time I type in an URL in chrome. e.g., https://youglish.com/getbyid/124594354/get%20caught%20off%20guard/english/us. It won't copy the URL to clipboard, only after I refresh the page it works fine. @James D

Comment: find out where the issue is. the setInterval should set on findshareLinkLink. as the script might run before the share button is available